# Can I use HTTP POSTs? Is there a better alternative?

Tags: php, ajax, search, http

I am use to php development in general and I am use to getting a lot done by making a `POST` to a php file.  However I have not seen people using `$_POST` in WordPress.  I have seen one discussion about someone wanting to create new posts on their blog using `$_POST`, and they were directed to a more secure system.  (Perhaps I misunderstood the conversation though.)

I would still like to use `$_POST` simply as a part of the user interface.

If it is possible and not a horrible idea to use $_POST what do I need to know to make $_POST work well with WordPress?  Are there rules about making a $_POST, or how redirecting so that nothing interferes with WordPress behavior?  Are there any other special considerations?

Comment: Yes, you can do AJAX programming. Now what is the question, really?

Comment: Okay you got me, added the real question to the bottom.

Comment: We have a one question per question rule, anything other than your main focus can you split it off so that they can be answered separately? If you don't then your question won't get as many answers and runs the risk of being too broad ( what if someone declines to answer because they have an answer for the first question but not the second? )

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is an HTTP/PHP web application. The ordinary rules of HTTP and PHP apply, and work. WordPress itself uses `$_POST` and `$_GET` more times than I can count. If you want to pass information from one page to another-- say from a form to a search handler-- you have to use one or the other.

There are some helper functions like [`add_query_arg()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) that might be applicable but as written your question is too broad to allow for specifics.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that if you're implementing your own `$_POST/GET` variables, make sure you avoid conflicts with built-in WordPress ones:

```
array(
    'm',
    'p',
    'posts',
    'w',
    'cat',
    'withcomments',
    'withoutcomments',
    's',
    'search',
    'exact',
    'sentence',
    'calendar',
    'page',
    'paged',
    'more',
    'tb',
    'pb',
    'author',
    'order',
    'orderby',
    'year',
    'monthnum',
    'day',
    'hour',
    'minute',
    'second',
    'name',
    'category_name',
    'tag',
    'feed',
    'author_name',
    'static',
    'pagename',
    'page_id',
    'error',
    'comments_popup',
    'attachment',
    'attachment_id',
    'subpost',
    'subpost_id',
    'preview',
    'robots',
    'taxonomy',
    'term',
    'cpage',
    'post_type',
    'post_format',
)
```